# how to write case statement with update in hive

Tags: hive

```
UPDATE  fact_orders1
SET m_order_created = (CASE WHEN fact_orders1.order_number = so.order_num THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
WHERE order_number in (
  SELECT so.order_num 
  FROM s_order so
  JOIN s_order_item soi ON so.ROW_ID = soi.ORDER_ID
  JOIN s_product sp ON soi.PROD_ID = sp.ROW_ID
  JOIN s_order_type sot ON so.ORDER_TYPE_ID = sot.ROW_ID 
  JOIN s_order_x sox ON so.ROW_ID=sox.PAR_ROW_ID
  WHERE (SUBSTR(LTRIM(sp.NAME), 1,3) IN ('VIP','BIZ')
  OR sp.NAME IN ('HSBB Business 10 Mbps','HSBB Business 20 Mbps','HSBB Residential 10 Mbps','HSBB Residential 20 Mbps'))
  AND sot.NAME = 'New Install' AND sp.PROD_CD = 'Promotion' AND sox.ATTRIB_11 = 'Y'
)
```

Error

> ====
>   FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10004]: Line 1:82 Invalid table alias or column reference 'so': (possible column names are: order_number, created, last_upd, m_order_created)

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reference table from the subquery in the outer query, the error is in the 2nd line :

```
CASE WHEN fact_orders1.order_number = so.order_num THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

`so` qualifier is will not be evaluated, you need to join `fact_orders1` and `order_num` in order to match `order_number` and `order_num`.

Comment: can u write the sample query using update and case classes for above i am not getting . thank u